# Amplify build fails due to '"appRoot" key needs to be a string'

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, aws-amplify, monorepo

After merging a new pull request in my GitHub repository, the automatic build of my Amplify App fails due to 'Invalid Monorepo spec provided. The "appRoot" key needs to be a string'.

I have not changed any of the settings of the repository or amplify app including the environment variables. When checking the environment variables and build settings, they both look like this:
[build settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xD3Er.png)
[environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUOgl.png).

I have tried reconnecting the repository as well as merging a test pull request to trigger the automatic build, however it still fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by changing my yml from:

```
applications:
  - frontend: ...
    appRoot: frontend
  - backend: ...
```

to:

```
applications:
  - appRoot: frontend
    frontend: ...
    backend: ...
```

where the `appRoot: frontend` is the root of my monorepo

Answer (score -1):

Others seem to be running into this as well, this [Issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/3900) has a resolution that seems to be working.

In short, a recent validation was added for the `buildSpec`. One possible work-around is to remove the `appRoot` key.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Thank you for posting that link, I will be keeping an eye on that thread. However, the proposed solution in the thread did not work for my Amplify project.